# @RequestMapping("/main") does not work in netbeans spring 4 it is working in spring 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, netbeans

@RequestMapping("/main")  does not work in netbeans spring 4 it is working in spring 3. same thing when i am using in spring framework 3.0 it is compleletly working fine but dont know why it is not working in spring framework 4.

when i am trying to open with 
url: http://localhost:8080/AnotationMultiactionDemo/main
it is not going to open.

please help me......

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="MylController" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />


</beans>
```

**mainController**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package MylController;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
/**
 *
 * @author Juned Ansari
 */
@Controller
public class mainController {
    @RequestMapping("/main")
    public ModelAndView hithere() {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");
        mav.addObject("welcomeMessage", "Hi there");

        return mav;
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not working? Doesn't "/main" get mapped? Do you get a 404? Please paste the error message if you can.

Comment: yes i am getting 404 when i type /main

Comment: Where is your index file located? I'm guessing it's in the wrong folder, the error message probably says index.html not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During my analysis on your code ( *pressumably I have brain* )

1).Missing *`xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"`*  that will enable `<context:component-scan>`

2). Why do you use? (I think you're not  having such *applicationContext.xml* there in *WEB-INF*) beside I also don't have such file so I commented it otherwise it will throw error

```
 <!--    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>-->
```

3).  I changed *xsi : schemaLocation* to

```
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd"
```

4). Some incompatibility stuff in spring 4 that I can't afford to explain .

So here's your fixed codes:

[image]

*mainController.java*

```
package MylController;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
/**
 *
 * @author Juned Ansari
 */
@Controller
public class mainController {
    @RequestMapping("/main")
    public ModelAndView hithere() {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("index");
        mav.addObject("welcomeMessage", "Hi there");

        return mav;
    }
}
```

*dispatcher-servlet.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">  
    <context:component-scan base-package="MylController"/> 

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />    
</beans>
```

*web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<!--    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
   <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>-->
   <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

*index.jsp*

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       ${welcomeMessage}
    </body>
</html>
```

Now request it with ***http://localhost:8080/AnotationMultiactionDemo/main***